# Is there a way of getting only the expanded parts of a glob pattern?

Tags: shell

Say I have a directory with contents

```
$ ls
1a.png
1b.xml
1c.png
2d.png
2e.xml
2f.png
```

Is there something that would act like the command `xglob` here?

```
$ xglob "1*.png" #xglob is the command I seek
a
c
```

While a pure `sh` solution is preferrable, a solution in `bash` or `fish` would also be helpful.

Comment: can you elaborate what xglob do or its usage ?

Comment: POSIX `sh` does not have anything like this.

Comment: @HarshGundecha `xglob` is just a name I gave a command that would solve my problem. I am looking for a way to implement it in shell script. It would return the text that individual glob characters would be expanded to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use capturing groups in regular expressions to see which parts of a string are matched by a certain part of the expression:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *
do
  if [[ "$f" =~ ^"1"(.*)".png"$ ]]
  then
    echo "$f matches, and the subsection is ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  fi
done
```